# SUMIF used together with FILTER function in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: filter, sum, google-docs, sumifs

It seems that Google Docs doesn't offer the SUMIFS function.
Instead, it was suggested to use a workaround combining SUM with FILTER

I'm trying to sum values filtering months in a specific year.

I've created a formula like this: =sum(FILTER(H:H,A:A>="01/02/2013",A:A<="28/02/2013")) but something must be wrong, I have an error message.

H = values
A = dates

I made another test, creating two cells with the dates. E.g. cell L3 with the date 01/02/2013, and cell M3 with the date 28/02/2013

Formula used is: =sum(FILTER(H:H,A:A,">="&L3,"<="&M3)) - Didn't work as well.

Can anybody find what is wrong in it? (the DD/MM/YYYY is setted as correct = portuguese language - so it's not MM/DD/YYYY).

thanks.

[I've shared by link the Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsByd8rO84TZdEtJNVV0NnBZZUd0QjJHQktzX2tSeEE&usp=sharing), only for view, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, I found a solution. Try using: `=subtotal(109;B2:B999)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use two SUMIFS like this

`=sumif(A:A,">="&L3,H:H)-sumif(A:A,">"&M3,H:H)`